# How to precisely edit segment angles and lengths in a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I want to take a path I've created and transform it into a uniform, precise "zig-zag" consisting of equal length lines at alternating angles (45 and 315).

[image: less rough]

What is the best way to do this?

I've tried creating line segments and joining them but end up with jagged corners.

[image: corners]

I tried sketching roughly what I want and going in to edit the line segments' length and angles, which seems like the way to go, but I don't see any way to do input precise attributes like I can when laying a line down.

[image: rough]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually creating and rotating the lines at 45 and -45 degrees and then joining them is honestly the easiest way of doing it.

Try this again.

- Create two lines
- Rotate one to 45 degrees and the other to -45
  degrees
- Make sure that the two anchor points intersect
- Select both and Join

[image]

There's really not much you can do wrong here...

Comment: Thanks. I must be missing something in that I can't get my anchors to intersect. The guide is snapping on the midpoint. I see you're selecting the anchor of the right line. Are you using select or direct select? Any modifiers?

Comment: I am using Direct Select tool (A) and snap it to the other anchor point while holding Ctrl.

Comment: As a workaround, you can always use the rectangle tool to create a square and then use the scissors from under the eraser to cut from the diagonal points, leaving you with two half of squares. you rotate one to 45 degrees and there you have it.

Comment: That's it Alin. Thanks! I need to get a modifier / selector cheat sheet.

Comment: @OrangeKid You are welcome! Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

or.. mathematically speaking.. hehe

create a straight line.. add points (any number of corners you needed). click. first point allocate it to x 0 y 0.. 
then succeeding points for even (2nd,4th,6th...) add x +1 y +1 .. 
then for succeeding points for odd (3rd,5th,7th...) add x +1 y-1 (or) x -1 y +1

thats it.. i think .. god speed..